# CSS Shadow for two boxes as one

Tags: html, css, shadow

Due to my website designed, i need to join two divs, and they need to look as one.

So no borders, and everything white, they look the same div.

Now i need to add a shadow, and things get complicated!

So far i achieve this, but i cant figure it out how to make it look nice!

```css
#one {
  height: 300px !important;
  width: 300px !important;
  float:left;
  box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px 0px #888888 !important;
}
#two {
  float:right;
  height: 300px !important;
  width: 300px !important;
  
  box-shadow:1px 1px 1px 0px #888888 !important;
}
#wrapper{
width:600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one">The two divs are</div>
    <div id="two">next to each other.</div>
</div>
```

I need to remove that line in the middle, and also at the bottom you can se a little gap.

Please help!

Comment: I'd suggest putting the drop shadow on the container rather than the individual elements. I don't see how a design could call for this.

Comment: Im edditing woocomerce, and there is no container :s

Comment: Is wrapper a container? Or can you add your own? There's no way (AFAIK) to do your requested styling.

Answer (score 4):

As has been mentioned in the comments, you should be looking to apply the `box-shadow` on the container and not on the inner elements. That would allow to display as if the shadow effect was applied on a single element. I guess that is what you are looking for. See the snippet below.

```css
#one {
    height: 300px;
    width: 40%;
    float:left;
}
#two {
    float:right;
    height: 300px;
    width: 40%;
}
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 3px #888;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one">Left-floated</div>
    <div id="two">right-floated.</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Again, if you are looking to make the `div`'s perfectly align next to each other without any blank space in between, you can remove the `width` property from both the inner and outer elements and add `display: inline-block;`. This would ensure that the outer as well as the inner containers
only take up as much space as needed horizontally. See this below :

```css
#one {
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
#two {
    float:left;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 3px #888;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one">The two divs are &nbsp;</div>
    <div id="two">next to each other.</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The below snippet is just an example of how the outer container would expand based on the content it contains:

```css
#one {
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
#two {
    float:left;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 3px #888;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one">Just random text to increase width The two divs are &nbsp;</div>
    <div id="two">STILL next to each other.</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!!!